# How to set up apollo client:check in react?

Tags: javascript, react-apollo, apollo-client

Does anybody has implemented Apollo client:check?

Does anybody has a good example?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What have you tried already that hasn't worked? The link you posted just looks like a `man` page for the `apollo` cli.

Comment: Trying to set up Apollo cli and run apollo client:check to check a project against a pushed service...

Comment: OK, so what is the data you want to pass to the `apollo client:check`. All the options are documented at the link you sent, so just update your question with exactly what you want to do. Right now, all you have said is that you want to run `apollo client:check`. What endpoint are you trying to hit? What is the clientReferenceId?

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't have specific enough details, but this is what you need to do. Install the apollo-cli:

`$ npm install -g apollo`

Run this command:

`$ apollo client:check`

And pass it any arguments that it needs to get the job done, such as:

```
apollo client:check  --clientReferenceId=34qo4af9o8q34 --key=SOMEAPIKEY --endpoint=https://some.enpoint
```